# C# пропадание изображения на control при создании формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Мной был создан класс для создания кастомных кнопок (монохромная иконка кнопки при наведении обрисовывается белым кругом)

```
public partial class RoundButton : PictureBox
{
    Icon ico;//рабочая иконка кнопки
    public RoundButton(Icon ico)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        Width = 38; Height = 38;
        this.ico = ico;
        MouseHover += RoundButton_MouseHover;
        MouseLeave += RoundButton_MouseLeave;
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler( RoundButton_Paint);
        this.OnPaint(null);
    }

    static readonly Color ColorActive = Color.FromArgb(0xe0, 0xe0, 0xe0);
    static readonly Color ColorBack = Color.FromArgb(0x21, 0x21, 0x21);
    static readonly byte lineWidth = 3;

    //рисуем стартовое отображение
    private static void RoundButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        RoundButton target = (RoundButton)sender;
        using (Graphics g = target.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.Clear(ColorBack);
            g.DrawIcon(target.ico, 3, 3);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("1","отладка");
    }

    //рисуем без обводки
    private void RoundButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoundButton target = (RoundButton)sender;
        using (Graphics g = target.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.Clear(ColorBack);
            g.DrawIcon(target.ico, 3, 3);
        }
    }

    //рисуем с обводкой
    private static void RoundButton_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoundButton target = (RoundButton)sender;
        using (Graphics g = target.CreateGraphics())
        {
            using (Pen pn = new Pen(ColorActive, lineWidth))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.Clear(ColorBack);
                g.DrawEllipse(pn, 1, 1, target.Width - 3, target.Height - 3);
                g.DrawIcon(target.ico, 3, 3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

добавляется контрол так:

```
        RoundButton HideButton = new RoundButton(Properties.Resources.Minimize);
        MessageBox.Show("2","отладка");
        HideButton.Left = 7;
        HideButton.Top = 52;
        RightPanel.Controls.Add(HideButton);
        MessageBox.Show("3","отладка");
```

Загвоздка в следующем:
При запуске приложения появляются messagebox'ы 1,2,3, затем появляется сама форма с кнопкой (изображение видно), затем вновь появляется отладочный Messagebox 1 (вызов события Paint)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 я нажимаю на ОК **и изображение на кнопке пропадает**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При наведении на кнопку срабатывает MouseOver-событие и изображение на кнопке появляется вновь.

**Как сделать кнопку видимой изначально?**